# Function to sum by pixel order in R

Tags: raster, r, raster-calculator, overlay

I am trying to quantify the number of months required to reach a specific value at the grid level. For this, the monthly raster values were then ranked, and the time length was defined as the number of months required to reach the total value.

I have built a function using raster::overlay to solve this, but how do I include the order of the pixels in function?

Here is my code.

```
library(raster)

# Rasters at monthly basis (represent 3 months)
r <- raster(nr=100, nc=100)
r[] = sample(ncell(r))

r2 <- r
r2[] = sample(ncell(r))

r3 <- r
r3[] = sample(ncell(r))

# Total value raster
r4 <- mean(r, r2, r3)*0.8

# Rank pixels by month
rm <- stack(r,r2,r3)
rm_ord <- calc(r_m,function(x, ...) order(x,decreasing=T) )

# Function for count n months to reach the total value 
count_m <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4) {
  ifelse(x1 >= x4, 1,
   ifelse(x1 + x2 >= x4, 2,
      ifelse(x1 + x2 + x3 >=x4, 3, 0)))
}

# Compute time length in n months
s <- stack(rm, r4)    
test <- overlay(s, fun=count_m)

plot(test)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? Why is the 'total' value actually taking the mean rather than summing the values in each raster. You might try using calc instead of overlay

Comment: Actually the total value raster represents just a threshold. The point is how to include in the function the order of the pixels over months (rm_ord) in order to sum first greater values and count the number of months required to reach this threshold value at the pixel level.

Comment: So in the count_m function, you want x1 to always be the greatest pixel value, x2 the second greatest, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to make sure that in your `count_m` function x1 is the greatest pixel value in the stack, x2 is the second greatest, and so on. You can do that by changing two lines:

```
# Create rm_ord using the actual pixel values instead of layer indices
rm_ord <- calc(r_m,function(x, ...) x[order(x,decreasing=T)])
```

and

```
# Use rm_ord instead of rm to create s
s <- stack(rm, r4)
```

However, using this method the resulting raster `test` will always have the value 1. The greatest value will *always* be greater than the mean, so you wont ever get passed the first `ifelse()`. Perhaps I've misunderstood your question ... maybe it would make more sense to compare in ascending order (i.e. remove `decreasing=T`)?

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but in fact I have to compute the greatest value pixel over the month's layers (rm) to be sure I have the greatest value for that pixel over the whole time series.

Comment: Hmmm I still don't understand what you are asking. Might be helpful if you gave 3 pixel values as an example and explain exactly what your expected outcome is

Comment: I see. So, x1, x2, x3 represent three different month layers. I have to count how many months it is necessary to sum to reach the threshold value (x4) at the pixel level. For instance,  x1[1,1] = 1,  x2[1,1] = 2, x3[1,1] = 3 and x4[1,1] = 3, so after ordering the values over the month's layers I will find that I need just 1 month (x3) to reach the threshold. This should be applied for all pixels in order to have as an outcome a raster layer showing the number of months (values 1, 3 (min, max)) necessary to reach the threshold

Comment: But where are you getting x4=3?? Your formula `r4 <- mean(r, r2, r3)*0.8` would result in a value of 1.6 .... Editing the two lines as I mentioned above will result in the the outcome you describe ... but it that outcome is always one. I think you need to rethink how you are calculating your threshold

Comment: You are right! The threshold was a bad example in this case, but using the entire database it worked now. Thank you very much!